# Python json.load() doesn't work in PHP exec()

Tags: php, python, json, exec

I have a python script that I wish to run from PHP using the exec() function.  What the Python script does is it gets some data from a web API, stores the data in temporary files, then reads the files and puts some data in a csv file.  The script runs fine when I test it alone.  Now, I want to run it through exec().  When I first tried, I thought that the script wasn't running at all, but then I looked a bi further and realized that the script WAS in fact running, but stopped somewhere during the execution.

I then tried to redirect the output to a txt file with `> output.txt` to see where it went wrong.  When I checked in the file and debugged a bit, I realized that the problem was the function `json.load()` in my Python script.  The strange thing is that in the `output.txt` file, there is no error message displayed.

Here is what the `output.txt` file looks like.

[image: output.txt]

And here is the python function that contains `json.load()`.

```
def get_json_files_data(path, min = 1):

    json_files = find_files(path, "json", min)
    json_data = dict()

    print("===========================================")
    print("= Converting JSON data into Python object =")
    print("===========================================")

    for file in json_files:
        base = os.path.basename(file) # name with extension (ex. 'file.json')
        id = os.path.splitext(base)[0] # name without extension (ex. 'file') in this case, the names are the trip ids
        opened_file = open(file)
        print(10)
        json_data[id] = json.load(opened_file)  # get the json data as a python dict
        print(11)
    return json_data
```

I also tried to change the permission of the json files to `777`, but that doesn't resolve the problem.

Does anyone have any idea?  Let me know if any more code is needed.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's happening when you don't close() files properly? Try using context manager `with open(file, 'r') as opened_file:` https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/

Comment: `json.load()`,  Where do you load content from? It should be `json.load(opened_file)`

Comment: @AlexeyDolgopolov yes sorry, it is, I just  accidentally removed it when editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work.  Here's the solution if anyone is wondering.

The problem was the encoding.  It was somehow different depending on how I was running the script.  What I did was simply to specified the encoding with `encoding='utf-8'`.  Here's what my code looks like now.

```
def get_json_files_data(path, min = 1):

    json_files = find_files(path, "json", min)
    json_data = dict()

    print("===========================================")
    print("= Converting JSON data into Python object =")
    print("===========================================")
    for file in json_files:
        base = os.path.basename(file) # name with extension (ex. 'file.json')
        id = os.path.splitext(base)[0] # name without extension (ex. 'file') in this case, the names are the trip ids
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as opened_file:
            json_data[id] = json.load(opened_file)  # get the json data as a python dict

    return json_data
```